# Adding event listener to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs, listener

I would like to listen for a change of the iframe window.location or document.src from my extJS app.

So I added listeners to the component, logged what the component is and found the content - and the document.src.

What I don't know: how to listen for the change of the document.src string?

```
Ext.widget('window',{
    layout: 'fit',
    items : [{
        xtype : "component",
        autoEl : {
            tag : "iframe",
            src : helpURI.replace('EN',Message.LOCALE.toUpperCase())
        },
        listeners: {
            load: {
                element: 'el',
                fn: function () {
                    this.parent().unmask();
                    console.log(this.dom.contentDocument.src);
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: I don't think document has an "src" property.

Comment: Well, I did console.log on the object... and chrome debugger shows the complete object, with every field and subobject. That's how I found it in the first place.

Comment: Btw, If you want to capture window.location change you could use the unload event for the window. Keep in mind that the location change should come from a user trigged action. Maybe extjs has also a similar event.